# How do I make a download link for my html flask site?

Tags: python, html, flask, download, webserver

I’ve been in the process of making my own website using html and flask. I want to make a download link on my html page. How do I do that?

Comment: Next time, use Google to search for your question, and relevant answers on SO will appear at the top. The duplicate was the *first result* of a search for `flask download file`. Also, while you are composing your question, a list entitled **Questions that may already have your answer** shows up with potentially relevant questions. **Use that list** and open up the suggested questions in new tabs. This site has been around since 2008; if you suspect a question has already been asked, it probably has. Duplicates like this just waste time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(‘/’)
def home():
    return render_template(‘index.html’)

@app.route(‘/download’)
def download_file():
    p = “app.exe”
    return send_file(p,as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == “__main__”:
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Download Link</h1>
<p>
    <a href=“{{url_for(‘download_file’)}}”>Download</a>
</p>
```

It is **IMPORTANT** that app.exe is in the same file location as main.py!

Comment: And no, `app.exe` or whatever file you're downloading can be anywhere - you just need to supply a fully-qualified path. See the answers in the dupe for more information.